# I have problem with automatic build on open file in vscode with npm start after build app

Tags: npm, webpack, visual-studio-code, build

I run my app (Angular) with npm start and webpack compile and build works, but after a few minutes when I open some file in vscode, I have automatic build. I do not have any keyboard shortcuts etc. I tried to disable all extensions but the problem is the same.

Comment: can you post your `npm start` command please? Or just post `package.json`? I'm interested in the start property of package.json scripts property

Comment: @RazRonen I answered you bellow

Comment: Its uncommon to post question related stuff as an answer in stackoverflow. Can you please edit your question and post it there? Thanks.

Comment: Can you also post your webpack configuration? I want to see there isn't a watch configured?
And also files under`.vscode` root directory if you have any.

Comment: @RazRonen package: https://codeshare.io/5wggVJ   wabpack: https://codeshare.io/2KmmqN

Comment: @RazRonen any response?